# Questions regarding ios back-end programming (concept)

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, server, backend

thank you all for reading my question~

Before asking some (2~3) questions, I will briefly explain what I am trying to do. I am trying to build a turn based multiplayer (1 vs 1) game. I have a little knowledge of Swift/IOS development, mysql, html, and jsp. I am planning to learn php since many people say combination of mysql and php is good for ios back-end programming.

Here are actual questions:

1. Do I need to get a droplet from places like Digital Ocean and deploy my own server? Or is it possible to use web hosting such as bluehost for this purpose?
2. This is the part which I have no clue about... How do I actually develop a multiplayer game? I can guess that this has something to do with tcp/ip socket programming. My experience with tcp/ip programming did not require mysql or something similar if I remember it correctly. In that vein, what's the role of some database like mysql when it comes to developing a multiplayer game? Of course it becomes handy when saving scores and achievement; however, I do not know why it is required for finding a match and establishing a connection. Wouldn't a private server needed instead for receiving and sending sockets? Does this mean I have to lease a dedicated server and setup everything by myself?

It seems like there are more than three questions... sorry for asking too many questions. I am a noob programmer and needs many advice from experts!

3. Is is necessary for me to deploy a web application for handling all backend stuffs? By the way, I am trying to avoid having users make an account. As a result, if I have to manage each user, maybe keeping each user's unique phone id can help me distinguish each user?

I have looked into both Google's and Apple's free game match system... It is very tempting to use them, but my friends designed game match screen and separate ranking systems. As so, I need to come up with a way to solve this conundrum. Please help me!!! Thank you all for reading my question again and help a poor soul here...

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. There is nothing wrong with your project, but you likely are trying to solve too many problems at once. Start simple and grow. Learn to build a small iOS app that implements a simple form of your game locally with no server (let players hand the device around). Then explore simple network solutions. Then worry about how you host it. StackOverflow will be very helpful as you find specific difficulties that have singular solutions. But it is not well designed to answer open-ended "how do I write a…" questions.